# What is the correct plot syntax for agent variables in NetLogo 5.1?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to find the correct syntax for plotting agent variables in NetLogo 5.1.

I am attempting to plot the energy of breed SHARKS which varies according to their feeding and swimming.

The example plot syntax from the Traffic Basic model is: `plot [speed] of sample-car`

However, if I therefore try: `plot [energy] of shark 1` then it throws this error :

> PLOT expected input to be a number but got the list [-7465] instead.

If I use a `plot mean [energy] of shark 1` then it works (because it's the mean value of just one agent).

Is the plot function expecting an operator applied to the agent variable?  If so, is there a list of accepted variables?  I feel the transition docs are lacking in this area.

Thanks

// EDIT:  Here's a simplified code of the shark/energy set-up.  I still get the same error, even with this.

```
breed [sharks shark]
sharks-own [energy]

to setup
 clear-all 

  create-sharks 1 [
     set energy 100
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask sharks [
    fd 1  
    set energy energy - 1  
  ]  

  tick
end
```

Comment: `plot` just takes a number. `[speed] of sample-car` just evaluates to a number. I would expect `[energy] of shark 1` to evaluate to a number as well, unless the `energy` of `shark 1` really is a list of one number. Are you sure it's just a number?

Comment: I don't think it's a list, but I will check of course. Haven't got on to lists yet, so maybe I created one by accident.

Comment: Post the code where you're setting `energy` if you'd like help.

Comment: You could use code like `ask shark 1 [ if is-list? energy [ show "oops" ] ]` to check it.

Comment: Oh, Solved.  The first shark is "shark 0", not "shark 1" !!  Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: “I still get the same error” — an error, yes, but surely not the same error at all.

Comment: Please either answer your own question, so there's an answer for the record — or simply delete the question, so it doesn't show up in future searches.